# in appengine how do i get foo.cust-one.com, foo.cust-two.com etc. to point to foo.appspot.vom

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

If foo is a google appengine app that can be accessed at both foo.appspot.com
and www.mydomain.com

How do I get various publishers to be able to access this by pointing foo.theirdomain.com to theirdomain.mydomain.com or theirdomain.foo.appsopt.com.

One way is 
- theirdomain needs to setup a google apps account 
- and than install my app 
- and than specifically note that it can be accessed at url foo.theirdomain.com 
- and in their domain manager have foo.theirdomain.com point to ghs.google.com

What about domains that "do not have" a google apps account. How would they be able to get foo.theirdomain.com to point to either theirdomain.mydomain.com or theirdomain.foo.appspot.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer in your question is correct.  Currently their domain *[must](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/domain.html)* be setup as a Google Apps domain.  They do not have to use or enable any other services on the domain.